# How to hide root folders & files in dialog box vb.net

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

basically I am making trying to make a folder dialog box, to which if we give a root path it shows me that specific folder and its sub directories and files i don't want the unnecessary folders e.g parent folders of that root folder to appear for this am trying to make a custom(user) folder dialog box control. but still am unsure how to hide the parent folders.
My control in which i give root path: [My control output Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpyVp.png)

In the above picture i dont want to see the unnecessary folders existing above.
[I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snYMO.png)

I am really confused how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yet there is no way to select custom root folder. Perhaps, you can use custom selected path to navigate directly to your directory before calling dialogue.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = "Your Directory Path"
        FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End Sub
```

Comment: This will still Show all of the folders just like the second picture i shared i want to hide those upper unnecessary folders

Comment: for this, you'll need to customize the FolderBrowserDialogue control and your directory to be added in the control's root directories. There is solution for this in C# on link below.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4ba0955a-e963-4528-a5f0-105fa8536839/user-defined-rootfolder-for-folderbrowserdialog?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: But Now am stuck in adding levels to it for e.g if Folder A shows 30 sub directories inside it i want to do that it shows only up to user selection directories 15,10,5 or whatever users sets the data

Comment: actually a root directory or parent directory always shows its child directories and all of them. So i'll figure out other way to solve question.